# How to parse data in javascript file through .net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, xml, parsing

How to parse data in a java script file through `.net` .

I have an url like this :

```
http://..../xml/en/file_1.js
```

The data in my `.js` file is like this :

```
getdate(20140802,'','','',10,5);
getdate(20140802,'','','',10,5);
getdate(20140727,'','','',10,5);
getdate(20140727,'','','',10,5);
getdate(20140723,'','','',10,5);
getdate(20140723,'','','',10,5);
```

---

for example
I want to interpret `20140802` `to 02 as day and 08 as month and 2014 as a year` and so on through the whole file  ...

Comment: are you able to get the string "20140802" so that it is easy to parse as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1:** Read All Lines from the `JS` file.

**Step2:** from each Line get the substring from `(` to `next 8` characters(Date is 8 characters length)

**Step3:** you can Convert the obtained `date string` into `Date` Type using `ParseExact()` method by providing format `yyyyMMdd`

**Complete Solution:**

```
                String [] JSLines=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\\myfile.js");
                String strDate = "";
                for(int i=0;i<JSLines.Length;i++)
                {                        
                    strDate=JSLines[i].Substring(JSLines[i].LastIndexOf("(")+1,8);               
                    DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);                               
                }
```

Output: `myDate` Contains the `Date`

Answer (score 1):

So basically if you have a current date presented like yyyyMMdd,  you can parse it like :

```
    string d = "20131118"; 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    DateTime da = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyyMMdd", provider);
```

This will result in `DateTime` instance with

```
Day :   18
Month : 11
Year:   2013
```

Comment: thanks but i  don't ask basically about that , i ask how to  the load .js file and get all the numbers after the first circle bracket through all the file

Comment: @just_name: can build regular expression, for example with: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/